# atmel at91sam9g20 ethernet register addresses

Tags: processor, atmel

I have no real experience with hardware programming. I would like to know how to find out which registers, i.e their addresses, are used for an ethernet connection to send and receive information in a processer. In particular, for ATMEL's at91sam9g20 processor. I have searched the documentation and I'm not sure of the following of what I've found:
-Transmit data: signal name ETX0-ETX3. Receive data: signal name ERX0-ERX3.
Also, Offset: 0x18 Receive Buffer Queue Pointer Register and offset: 0x1C Transmit Buffer Queue Pointer Register.

I would appreciate any help as I'm very stuck on this issue. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [procesor documentation](http://www.atmel.at/Images/doc6384.pdf) you find the following:

- chapter 8 - **general memory mapping** - this gives the offset of the EMAC memory block as `0xFFFC:4000`
- chapter 36 - description of the Ethernet MAC subsystem
- item 36.3.2 - memory interface - tells how the memory buffers for RX and TX is set up
- item 36.5 - **user interface** - table 36-6 gives the names and offsets to all registers used by the subsystem

The signals (=pins) and register offsets you describe are correct.